# Connecting two devices using libgdx

Tags: android, connection, p2p, libgdx, device

I'm developping a video game on both pc and android using libgdx.
And i would like to connect them by Wifi or Bluetooth on a local network. The idea is to play in p2p, establishing this connection easily. 
Please anyone can give help or source code for that, knowing that the connections can be : android/android but also PC/PC (since libgdx allows that)? I have absolutely no idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Well because libgdx doesn't have good networking support you can write your own, but i've found that [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) is very good. It takes a lot of the hassle out of writing the network layer of your application and I've used it to connect mobile and desktop with no problems. Definably worth a quick view. It also has some good examples to get your up and running with a network game too.

I've also found [this article](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking) by valve very usefull.

Comment: Kryonet is good, but it's not possible to export an iOS app using LibGDX + Kryonet yet.

Comment: iOS doesn't support any of the Kryonet library when it's converted over for iOS use.

Comment: I thought that the RoboVM is based on Android, and since android includes all the standard classes so KryoNet should work... What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: RoboVM has only been properly released for use within the past few days. Your comment was posted in August.

Comment: At the time, iOS port also hadn't been released :)

Comment: Well that leaves me a little bit red-faced.. Dam this internet thing for keeping good records :)

Comment: Awesome Valve link! I was doing all the Kryonet stuff with just Java, total waste of time given Kryonet is so easy!

Answer (score 2):

Networking is somewhat beyond the scope of Libgdx.  There is some basic support for HTTP GET/POST/PUT, but it implies you already have a DNS name or IP address to connect to, which usually implies you have a relatively fixed "server" to connect to (not an arbitrary peer).  Peer-to-peer networking is definitely beyond the scope of Libgdx.

On the upside, since Android and Desktop networking are already pretty close, you can use most any pure-Java networking infrastructure that supports peer-to-peer.  See other Stack Overflow questions like: [Peer-to-Peer communication options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041426/peer-to-peer-communication-options)  I think you'll discover that the really hard part of peer-to-peer networking is "discovery" (that is figuring the address of the peer you care about).

Answer (score 1):

There is little to no documentation on it, but LibGDX does have a **platform independant** *(Android, Desktop, iOS and GWT)* socket class.
I'd link you to an example of it's usage, but as I stated; there's no written documentation/example.

However, I can give you this link as a good starting point.

> http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html

Answer (score 0):

libgdx-net looks good. https://github.com/pepedeab/libGDX-Net

Ive not yet tested it myself though.

Comment: It's quite outdated now, and also doesn't yet support iOS.