# XMPP python: Send a private message to one of several users logged on with the same jid

Tags: python, xmpp, xmpppy

In my situation, I have might have userA and userB logged on to google talk with using us@gmail.com, while userC and userD are logged on to google talk using them@gmail.com.

How might userA send a message that only userC will see, and userC verify that a given message is from userA?

I am still new to xmpp, and I am having trouble gauging whether this requires muc or not. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I have a good deal of code written in python so far that interprets the messages, so if there is a simple way to do this with xmpppy or the like, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2473747/234938) about using full JIDs with resources, as opposed to "bare" JIDs like "them@gmail.com".

Comment: Ok, I am going to try that now.