# How does Google Talk replicate messages across devices?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I'm wondering how (official) GTalk clients manage to show **all** messages received - even if it was originally consumed by another client. For example: I'm logged into GTalk on gmail.com on my laptop and, at the same time, via the official GTalk app on my Android device. A friend sends me a message, which is displayed on **both** the gmail.com client and the Android client. (I think it's originally only forwarded to one of either clients, but the second client fetches the message later on)

I recently found out that there's a very similar XMPP feature, called [Carbons](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html). However, after a quick service discovery request Google's servers didn't advertise this feature. XEP-0313 and XEP-0136 look good too, but the servers don't advertise them either.

Possibly related question: [Deliver Google Talk message to all logged in clients using XMPPPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144421/deliver-google-talk-message-to-all-logged-in-clients-using-xmpppy)

Answer (score 2):

When you initiate a new chat then you should send the first message to the users bare Jid. This is what most clients are doing. When the GTalk server retrieves a chat message to a bare Jid it routes the message to all available resources. For all following messages in this conversation the clients normally pick up the Resource and send them to full Jids. The messages should not be replicated then.

Many other servers don't route message to bare Jids to all resources, but  to the most available resource which is the client with the highest priority.

Here is a quote form the RFC:

```
If there is more than one resource with a non-negative presence priority then the
server MUST either
(a) deliver the message to the "most available" resource or
resources (according to the server's implementation-specific algorithm, e.g., treating
the resource or resources with the highest presence priority as "most available") or
(b) deliver the message to all of the non-negative resources.
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I'll give it a try and see if I can reproduce the behavior of official clients.

Comment: I think that's not the answer TomTastche was expecting. I will answer below

Answer (score 1):

XEP-0280 defines this. As I understand, it defines the mechanism to notify all the resources from same user when one of them sends a message to anyone. I mean, Alice/pda sends a message to Bob, so Alice/mobile and Alice/PC will receive a copy of the message sent be Alice/pda.

Hope it helps. I am currently looking for a server that implements this, and also for a client library. If not, I will implement it by myself in both jabberd2 and gloox xmpp library.

Cheers,

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it working using Google's servers... Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: Finally I solved the problem by doing it by myself... I have just created a new tag into the message tag, which is called replica: <message>...<body>...</body>...<replica xmlns='urn:xmpp:replicas' to='gtp100003221'/></message>. I send this message to myself and all my resources will receive them as a message from myself. I know it's tricky but this is the only thing I can do for now, since XEP-0280 is not implemented in most of server implementations and client libraries.

Comment: This works for all XMPP-servers? Even using Google's servers?